# Deleting related rows from other tables without primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to delete the associated rows from the "assign" table when a crew member is deleted.

However, when I create the tables, I get the error:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "assign"
```

It seems as though I need distinct values in the "assign" table, but the whole point is that I want to delete all associated information when a crew member is removed. How can I do this?

```
create table flight(
  flight_num BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  source_city varchar,
  dest_city varchar,
  dep_time int,
  arr_time int,
  airfare int,
  mileage int
);

create table crew (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar,
  salary int,
  position varchar,
  seniority int,
  fly_hours int,
  mgrid int,
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES assign(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

create table assign (
  id int, # refers to a crew member id, not a row id
  flight_num int
);
```

Comment: To clarify, the "id" column in assign refers to a crew member's id, so it could have multiple of the same id in that column, because one crew member can be assigned to multiple flights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreign keys should be on the M-M join table, as so:

```
create table flight(
  flight_num int PRIMARY KEY,
  -- etc
);

create table crew (
  crew_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  -- etc
);

create table assign (
  crew_id int,
  flight_num int,
  -- If the corresponding record in either of these FKs is deleted then
  -- this record will be deleted.
  FOREIGN KEY (crew_id) REFERENCES crew(crew_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (flight_num) REFERENCES flight(flight_num) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  -- M-M usually should have a PK over both foreign columns, arranged in order
  -- of expected usage. A reverse covering index can be added if needed.
  PRIMARY KEY (flight_num, crew_id)
);
```

In this case the FKs are allowed because they are over a unique columns (PKs of `crew` and `flight`). The original error is because there was no unique contraint on the FK target (`assign.crew_id`).